# Xcode 4.4 , IOS 5.1 simulator. Twitter framework issue

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, twitter, app-store

Just upgraded to Xcode 4.4 in Mountain Lion and faced with an issue. Built-in Twitter framework doesn't work on IOS Simulator now. Looks like many developers who is upgraded to Xcode 4.4 have the same problem :

https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/4850

So the questions:

- Is it an issue of a simulator? Would that twitter-code work in real device?
- It's known that from IOS 6 it will be another built-in framework to connect with social media. Can the app with IOS 5 twitter-code be rejected from appstore now?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it an issue of a simulator? Would that twitter-code work in real device?

According to the thread you linked to it's a simulator-only problem. But you should **always** test your code on an actual iOS device before distributing to the store.

> It's known that from IOS 6 it will be another built-in framework to connect with social media. Can the app with IOS 5 twitter-code be rejected from appstore now?

Actually the Twitter framework was available as a built-in framework from iOS 5 onwards. So your iOS 5 compatible implementation isn't going to be rejected in iOS 6 (all things being equal). In fact, if you have a custom, non-'Twitter framework' integration this will still be acceptable - Apple aren't forcing you to use the supplied Twitter framework exclusively.